# How to select all lines maching a pattern?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to select all lines matching a pattern?

To illustrate, using column :

```
      1     2  3                                   1 2 3
   2     1  4      select all lines matching 1     2 1 4
1 2      2            :'<,'>!column -t             1 2 2
  3   2    3            ->                           3   2    3
 1 1   3                                           1 1 3
    4 4     4                                        4 4     4
```

Comment: well, in vi, if you know the pattern of lines, you can do modification directly without selecting.

Comment: It depends on the type of the command. Typically, that is not possible with a lot of external commands (sort, uniq, column)

Answer (score 12):

If I well understood your question, the answer is quite simple:

```
qregisterq
:g/pattern/y REGISTER
```

The first line is necessary to clean up the register's content, if you used it before.
In the second line it's important to capitalize the register's name because that means that you intend to append the content of each matching line, instead to substitute it.

To paste the matching lines simply do:

```
"registerp
```

or even more simple:

```
p
```

because `p` copy the content of the last register used.

For example, to select all lines matching 1 (using register `a`):

```
qaq
:g/1/y A
```

and then:

```
"ap
```

Answer (score 3):

Vim doesn't have the ability to match multiple separated lines by default.

You could look at [this script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=953), or [this one](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) (more up to date) and see if it works for you.

However, if you are just selecting the lines to perform a command on them, you can use the `:g` command to perform the command directly on those lines.

```
:g/regex/ex command
```

So for example:

```
:g/hello/d
```

Will delete all lines that match the regex `hello`

With the [multiple cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) plugin (also linked above) you can select multiple separated lines that match a regex:

```
:% MultipleCursorsFind Regex
```

This will select the lines for you and then you can execute any commands you like on them.

Comment: +1 The scripts look great. I gonna try them. But I think that's not possible to use external command on my selection

Comment: Using the multiple cursors plugin I think you can (I have edited in an example showing how)

Answer (score 2):

according to you example, i guess you want to delete all blank prefix where the lines having 1 in it. so in vi, we could do it without selecting:

```
:%s/\s*\(.*1.*\)$/\1
```

UPDATE:

always a way to solve your problem in a traditional vi way.

according to your new example, i think you want to delete all blanks in the lines with 1 in it. so we can:

```
:g/1/s/\s\+//g
```

or maybe you want to have one space left for alignment:

```
:g/1/s/\s\+/ /g
```

`g/1/` matches all lines in the file with 1 in it, `s/\s\+//g` substitutes all blanks to nothing globally in the scope of one line.

Comment: Yes, you're right... I change my example to fit my problem